# display records from a table using if statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, if-statement

I'm creating a weblog for my class project right now. Before this I have asked about limit displayed character and someone has helped me out. Right now I have 3 different types of post; Articles, Q&A and Videos but I put it in a same table. I want to display it by category and has pagination and I've done that. Inside Category.php I want to display the posts by category and order it by date desc order and if the user click on 'Read More' link, it will redirect them to a new page which contain full article. For example, if the user click on Q&A's 'Read More' link, it will redirect them to qna-single.php, if the user click on Video's 'Read More' link, it will redirect them to video-single.php.

Right now I'm using IF statement to get that result. Here is my PHP

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
$query1 = "SELECT articles.*, categories.category_name FROM articles, categories WHERE articles.article_category_id=categories.category_id AND categories.category_id='$id' and articles.article_type_id='1' ORDER BY article_id DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";
$result1 = mysql_query($query1);

$query2 = "SELECT articles.*, categories.category_name FROM articles, categories WHERE articles.article_category_id=categories.category_id AND categories.category_id='$id' AND articles.article_type_id='2' ORDER BY article_id DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);

$query3 = "SELECT articles.*, categories.category_name FROM articles, categories WHERE articles.article_category_id=categories.category_id AND categories.category_id='$id' AND articles.article_type_id='3' ORDER BY article_id DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";
$result3 = mysql_query($query3);
```

Here is how I display the results

```
if ($query1) { //display articles
while ($query_row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
{
$string1 = strip_tags($query_row1['article_content']);
if (strlen($string1) > 500) {
$stringCut1 = substr($string1, 0, 500);
$string1 = substr($stringCut1, 0, strrpos($stringCut1, ' '))."... <a href='article-single.php?id=".$query_row1['article_id']."' title='view details' class='more'>Read More</a>";
}

echo "<li>
        <div>
            <h4><a href='article-single.php?id=".$query_row1['article_id']."' title='view details'>".$query_row1['article_title']."</a></h4>
            <span>
                Posted in <a href = '#'>".$query_row1['category_name']."</a> by <a href=''>dr.nor</a> on <a href='#'>".$query_row1['article_date']."</a>
            </span>
        </div>
        <p>".$string1."</p>
    </li>";
}
}
if ($query2) { //display q&a
while ($query_row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
{
 $string2 = strip_tags($query_row2['article_content']);
if (strlen($string2) > 500) {
$stringCut2 = substr($string2, 0, 500);
$string2 = substr($stringCut2, 0, strrpos($stringCut2, ' '))."... <a href='qna-single.php?id=".$query_row2['article_id']."' title='view details' class='more'>Read More</a>";
}

echo "<li>
        <div>
            <h4><a href='qna-single.php?id=".$query_row2['article_id']."' title='view details'>".$query_row2['article_title']."</a></h4>
            <span>
                Posted in <a href = '#'>".$query_row2['category_name']."</a> by <a href=''>dr.nor</a> on <a href='#'>".$query_row2['article_date']."</a>
            </span>
        </div>
        <p>".$string2."</p>
    </li>";
}
}
if ($query3) { //display video
while($query_row3=mysql_fetch_assoc($result3)){

$string3 = strip_tags($query_row3['article_content']);
if (strlen($string3) > 200) {
$stringCut3 = substr($string3, 0, 200);
$string3 = substr($stringCut3, 0, strrpos($stringCut3, ' '))."... <a href='video-single.php?id=".$query_row3['article_content']."' title='view details' class='more'>Read More</a>";
}

$str = "<iframe id=\"player\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"700\" height=\"435\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/".$query_row3['article_video_link']."\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
echo "
    <li>
        <span></span>
        <div>
            <h4><a href='video-single.php?id=".$query_row3['article_id']."' title='view details'>".$query_row3['article_title']."</a></h4>
            <span>
                Posted in <a href = '#'>".$query_row3['category_name']."</a> by <a href=''>dr.nor</a> on <a href='#'>".$query_row3['article_date']."</a>
            </span>
        </div>
        <p>";
        echo stripslashes($str);
        echo "</p>
        <div class='h5'></div>
        <p>".$string3."</p>
    </li>";
}
}
```

The problem is, I want to display it by date no matter if it Article first, Video first or Q&A first, but it displayed by type of post (Article, Q&A, Video). I mean, after Article's loop end (order by date desc) it will continue to Q&A and so on. So, how can I solve this? *Sorry for my poor English, :)

Comment: Why do you have 3 different queries? Either UNION the three queries, and wrap them up with an ORDER BY, or (better idea) just change `articles.article_type_id='3'` to `articles.article_type_id IN(1,2,3)`, and add an ORDER BY to the end of that. - But maybe I don't really understand what you're doing.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure what I'm doing. But, what I can explain is I have tried before this using 1 query but it didn't display the result I want or I guess I'm not fully understand with it. So with this method I can get the results I want even this is not really what I want. Thank you for your feedback. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use three queries. You can get exact result from one query only.

Try this:

```
SELECT a.*, c.category_name
FROM articles a 
INNER JOIN categories c ON a.article_category_id = c.category_id 
WHERE c.category_id = '$id' AND a.article_type_id IN (1, 2, 3)
ORDER BY a.article_id DESC 
LIMIT $START, $LIMIT
```

Comment: Thank you for your promptly reply. Obviously it's more simpler and understandable than mine. I'll try to display the results the way I want. Thanks again! :)